# Show iOS keyboard in Safari after changePage in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I know showing the keyboard with a regular focus() is pretty much impossible without an onclick on iOS safari, but I am trying to do something a little different. Using jquery mobile I load two different pages (data-role="page") in the DOM. Both of these pages have text inputs on them. When the user taps the input on the first page I want to slide up the second page and focus on the input on the second page and have the keyboard show. I can accomplish this by creating a focus event listener on the first input and having a regular $('#secondpage').show() followed by a $('#secondinput').focus(). However, if I use changePage() instead of show() or even place an animation on .show() then the field won't be focused on and the keyboard won't show.

Here is my input from the first page:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" data-theme="A">
```

The entire second page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my javascript that works but does not give the desired transition I want, this is contained in a pageinit for the first page. Also in order to get this to work I must place a display:none on #page2:

```
$('#input1').on('tap', function() {
    $('#page2').show();
    $('#input2').focus();
});
```

The following code does not work:

```
$('#input1').on('tap', function() {
    $('#page2').show("slide", { direction: "up" });
    $('#input2').focus();
});
```

This doesn't work either (this would be the most preferable solution):

```
$('#input1').on('tap', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage('#page2', { transition: 'slideup' });
    $('#input2').focus();
});
```

Another thing I have tried is putting an onclick attribute on #input1, but no matter what I do any transition seems to kill the focus and the keyboard. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, you should focus the input2 only when the page2 has finished loading.

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('#input1').on('tap', function() {
        $.mobile.changePage('#page2', { transition: 'slideup' });

    }); 
    $("#page2").bind('pageshow', function() {
        $('#input2').focus();
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/SgFXx/1/)**

Comment: This isn't working for me on a phone. It works fine in a regular browser but on iOS safari the new page comes up but there is no focus on it and the keyboard isn't showing. With that being said, this is the exact behavior I am trying to accomplish, but I obviously want the keyboard to show at the end.

Comment: I think this is a feature of iOS it won't show the keyboard until and unless the user interacts with it.